# error al cargar un select

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js

la situación es que tengo un select de tipos de movimientos, espero que sea multiple pero no he podido asi que por el momento lo tengo solo con único, lo guardo bien, el me envía el datos la base y lo guarda por medio de axios, la cosa es que tengo un apartado de actualizar,quiero que le de buscar y me traiga la vista cargada, pero a la hora de tratar de llenar el select "tipo de movimientos" no logro que se llene, asp(donde trarigo los datos ya que es un api) me envía el dato, digamos que me envía servicio nuevo, pero no logro hacer que se cargue

-----datos del select------

```
              <v-flex xs10>
                  <v-select
                    v-model="tipoMovimiento"
                    :items="tipoMovimientos"
                    label="Tipo de movimiento"
                  ></v-select>
                </v-flex>

  tipoMovimientos: [
        { text: "Servicio Nuevo", value: "ServicioNuevo" },
        { text: "Cambio de medidor", value: "CambioMedidor" },
        { text: "Cambio de constante", value: "CambioConstante" },
        { text: "Cambio de Transf. corriente(TC)", value: "CambioTC" },
        { text: "Cambio de Transf. Potencial(TP)", value: "CambioTP" },
        { text: "Mantenimiento de equipo 3G", value: "Mantenimento3G" },
        { text: "Inspeccción de mantenimiento", value: "Inspeccion" },
        { text: "Interrogacion Remota 3g-AMI", value: "Interrogacion" },
        { text: "Cambio de sistema De medición(CL20-CL200)", value: "CambioSistema" },
        { text: "Generacion Distribuida", value: "Generacios Distribuida" },
        { text: "Traslado", value: "Traslado" },
        { text: "Desconexión", value: "Desconexion" }
      ],
```

De esta manera trato de cargarlo

me.subEstaciones = response.data.subEstaciones;

lo que me responde el data = tipo1: "CambioMedidor", osea si me trae el dato

Comment: Que tiene que ver subEstaciones con los datos de tu select? que viene en el data? probaste imprimirlo para ver que tipo de datos viene? que valor le estas pasando a fecha? por favor, usa el boton [edit] y completa la pregunta. Asi como esta, no podemos saber que esta pasando

Comment: hola, creo que ya formule mejor la pregunta, me podrías decir si esta bien? quite lo de la fecha ya que encontré un ejemplo y pude hacerlo, del otro si no encuentro nada

Comment: y que tiene que ver subEstaciones con lo que mandas al select?

Comment: perdon estoy tan loco con esa parte que ni me fijo que estoy subiendo,  no era subestaciones era tipo de movimientos

Comment: entonces arreglalo.. y de paso, mostra que viene en data

Comment: listo espero esta vez si jaja

Comment: no nos estamos entendiendo.. sigo sin saber que es subestaciones. sigo sin saber que vuelve en tu data y a quien se lo pasas. Sigo sin saber que quieres hacer con tu select y que datos recibe y como los recibe. Tomate unos minutos largos, y ordena toda tu pregunta. Asi como esta es totalmente confusa...

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que entiendo, subEstaciones seria el nombre de la lista que te devuelve la api, lo que tenes que hacer es inicializar por decirlo una lista luego en el metodo en dónde llamas la api lo igualas, parecido a lo que haces.

```
listaMovimientos = []
listarSelectMovimientos(){
this.listaMovimientos = response.data.subEstaciones
}
```

Igual podes mostrarnos con un console.log(response.data) para poder ver la estructura de la lista.

Comment: hola señor, ve , para explicarte mejor, la cosa es que o envió cierto, el select llamado subestaciones, bueno el me lo guarda todo bien , a la hora de querer recuperar lo, lo hago de la manera en la que tu me dices                              me.subEstaciones = response.data.subEstaciones;                                              de esa mara, pero no me sirve, lo que me responde el console log, es que viene vacio, pero a la hora de traer las cosas, me dice que viene cargado al,peor no lo inserta en el select